# Checkbox inputs badly aligned when there's no accompanying label using Bootstrap and MVC5

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[Bootply to play with](http://www.bootply.com/Awg2ElYTc6)

Visual Studio 2013 generates the following CSHTML when scaffolding an edit view for a model with a boolean:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsUrgent, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="checkbox">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsUrgent)
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After passing through Razor you get this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="IsUrgent">Is bad :(</label>
   <div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <input class="check-box" data-val="true" id="IsUrgent" name="IsUrgent" type="checkbox" value="true">
      <input name="IsUrgent" type="hidden" value="false">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Twitter Bootstrap 3.2 however doesn't like this way of using labels because this is the result:

[image: Screenshot]

Note that the checkbox is positioned too much to the left.

If I wrap my input in a dummy label with some whitespace, ie.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="IsUrgent">Is good!</label>

    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input class="check-box" data-val="true" id="IsUrgent" name="IsUrgent" type="checkbox" value="true">
        <input name="IsUrgent" type="hidden" value="false">&nbsp;</label>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I get this:

[image: Second screenshot]

which looks nice but it's not valid HTML:

> The label element may contain at most one input, button, select, textarea, or keygen descendant.

Am I doing something wrong with my CSS classes?

**Edit**

If I move the second `input` outside of the `label` as @Saranga suggests I'm still left with the redundant `label` that serves no semantic function ...

Comment: Is there a problem with including a rule on the site.css file: .checkbox > input[type=checkbox]{
    margin-left:0;
} ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I implemented an Html Helper CheckBoxForBootstrap that puts the checkbox in a label but without any label text so there is no redundant label but you still get the desired formatting. The hidden field needed by mvc model binder is added after the label to it should be valid html.

```
public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxForBootstrap(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
        string name, 
        bool isChecked)
{

    TagBuilder checkbox = new TagBuilder("input");
    checkbox.Attributes.Add("type", "checkbox");
    checkbox.Attributes.Add("name", name);
    checkbox.Attributes.Add("id", name);
    checkbox.Attributes.Add("data-val", "true");
    checkbox.Attributes.Add("value", "true");
    if (isChecked)
        checkbox.Attributes.Add("checked", "checked");

    TagBuilder label = new TagBuilder("label");
    //nest the checkbox inside the label
    label.InnerHtml = checkbox.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);

    TagBuilder hidden = new TagBuilder("input");
    hidden.Attributes.Add("type", "hidden");
    hidden.Attributes.Add("name", name);
    hidden.Attributes.Add("value", "false");

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(
    label.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal) 
    + hidden.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 32):

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsUrgent)
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsUrgent)
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: This will produce invalid HTML, ie. _The label element may contain at most one input, button, select, textarea, or keygen descendant._

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsUrgent)` add following code. You can put the hidden field outside the `label` tag.

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input class="check-box" data-val="true" id="IsUrgent" name="IsUrgent" value="true" type="checkbox"> &nbsp;
    </label>
    <input name="IsUrgent" type="hidden" value="false">
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.bootply.com/oCRnB3b521)

Thanks!

Comment: Sadly that hidden field is required by the MVC model binder :(. That's why `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsUrgent)` outputs both of them

Comment: True, but then I'm still stuck with the superfluous `label`

Comment: I think it's not superfluous one, because in `bootstrap` we define the text at the end of the check-box (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms), but in your case you need to keep the label in front. So we need that label with `&nbsp;` to get the `bootstrap` styles work. So we can use this method as a alternative. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and just changed the class on the div immediately surrounding the checkbox. Try:

```
    <div class="form-control-static">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsUrgent)
     </div>
```

Comment: A label when clicked will move the focus to the input field, this solution does not

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="checkbox" style="margin: 5px 0 0 0;">
    <label for="remember" style="margin: 0;">
        <input name="remember" id="remember" type="checkbox" style="margin-top: 2px;">
        Remember me
    </label>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/slTVEI1fSf)**

Comment: This solution puts the label to the right of the checkbox

Answer (score 1):

**Warning: Solution with CSS**

I solved it this way:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsRequired2, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-2 checkbox-form">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsRequired2)
    </div>
</div>
```

Using this CSS class:

```
.checkbox-form {
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

Which generates this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="IsRequired2" class="control-label col-md-2">Good!</label>

    <div class="col-md-2 checkbox-form">
      <input value="true" name="IsRequired2" id="IsRequired2" type="checkbox">
      <input value="false" name="IsRequired2" type="hidden">
    </div>
</div>
```

As can be seen [here](http://www.bootply.com/62A7bw4f7Q), it has the advantage of not adding extra vertical space before or after the checkbox line.

Answer (score 0):

you can try some code I have shared on my github account : [icheck-bootstrap](https://github.com/bantikyan/icheck-bootstrap)

You can see demo here:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bantikyan/icheck-bootstrap/9bd0c21a/icheck-bootstrap.min.css" />


<div class="checkbox icheck-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" id="someCheckboxId1" />
    <label for="someCheckboxId1">Clieck to check</label>
</div>

<div class="checkbox icheck-wisteria">
    <input type="checkbox" id="someCheckboxId2" />
    <label for="someCheckboxId2">Clieck to check</label>
</div>
```

Comment: The css you link to is over 24KB

Answer (score 0):

just remove the div whith the "checkbox" class sorrounding your'e checkbox and label and the problem will go away

Answer (score -1):

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.IsUrgent)
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <label>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsUrgent)
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and reverse order

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsUrgent)
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.IsUrgent)
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: This will produce invalid HTML, ie. _The label element may contain at most one input, button, select, textarea, or keygen descendant._